# How can I make this quadruped leg and foot rig behave itself?

Tags: rigging, bones

I am trying to make a rig such that one can push off the ground by the toes (or ball of the foot) and then later kick the toes back up and forward without moving the entire rest of the leg backwards. Is it possible to do this, and if so, how? Is there some obvious trick I am missing, or a better way to approach animating a foot interacting with the ground in general?

Ideally it would be nice to have a generalized solution so that one could easily push off the ground from any part of the foot (say, the side or back) for things like strafing around corners, scooting backwards, etc etc.

[image]